# Exponential growth between two values in python

Tags: python, numpy, exponential

As title, I need an array between two fixed values which follows and exponential growth. 
Just to explain better, I have initial weight and final weight values, and I want the values in the array going from the final weight value (1.08) to the initial weight (1.48) following an exponential growth.
Can someone help me?

Comment: It would be good if you could give a code example with this to show what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that?

```
np.logspace(np.log(1.08), np.log(1.48), 10, base=np.exp(1))
```

This prints:

```
array([1.08      , 1.11847936, 1.1583297 , 1.19959987, 1.24234045,
   1.28660384, 1.3324443 , 1.379918  , 1.42908315, 1.48      ])
```

The `10` is the number of steps, you can increase or decrease it.

Comment: Since there are infinite choices of base, there are infinite curves possible.